# How to deploy Ethereum Smart Contract through Brownie to the Private Network

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, brownie

I have a `geth` node that is connected to a private network on my computer that uses port: `8545`. Hence, I have a smart contract that is tested using [Brownie](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) on the `ganache-cli` network.

> `Brownie` is a Python framework for Ethereum smart contract testing,
>   interaction and deployment.

---

**=>** I want to deploy a smart contract using Brownie, how can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Connecting to the Network

First, make sure that Brownie is able to connect to your private network. You will have to [add a custom network](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/network-management.html#adding-a-new-network) to Brownie's network settings. Here is an example command that declares a live network with the name "private" at `127.0.0.1`, port 8545:

```
brownie networks add live private host=https://127.0.0.1:8545 chainid=1337
```

You can use `brownie networks --help` for more information on possible settings.

#### Deploying your Contract

The simplest way to deploy is via a [deployment script](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deploy.html#deploying-contracts). Here is an example deployment script for a basic ERC20, taken from the documentation:

```py
from brownie import *

def main():
    accounts[0].deploy(Token, "Test Token", "TEST", 18, "1000 ether")
```

Save your deployment script within the `scripts/` folder of your project.

To run the script on your local network, use the `--network` flag. For example, to run a deployment script named `deployment.py` on a network named "private":

```
brownie run deployment --network private
```