# How can I automize process of deploying my contract?

Tags: contract-deployment, brownie

I am using following appoach [How to deploy Ethereum Smart Contract through Brownie to the Private Network](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/78426/4575).

I want to automate this process in order to capture the `transaction hash` and deployed contract's `address`, and its `abi`.

Afterwards save them under a `json` file for my future use, instead of copy and paste them by hand.

**[Q]** How can I accomplish it?